# Create a shape from the other

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

Three days of trying to create a dynamic figure in the other figures, it does not work.

Using THREE.ExtrudeGeometry, turned:
[image: http://f3.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhBW.png]

But the "tail" should be the radius:
[image: http://f3.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhC1.png]

None of the parameters ExtrudeGeometry not allow him to do.
Draw in the 3D editor and then figure this place it will not work because, as the size has to dynamically changes

How to implement it?
Or how to glue two planes, a set of arcs and make the whole figure?
[http://f4.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhCj.png http://f4.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhCj.png](http://f4.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhCj.png)

Comment: Really there is no question here or enough information of the problem.

Comment: TubeGeometry can give you a bent tube, but it has no thickness. I am afraid three.js cannot create the shape you want.

Comment: @WestLangley, Not quite, [link](http://f1.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhDe.png), it can make bevel, so it can be deformed radius, it only need invert

Comment: @gaitat,thanks,fixed question

Comment: @WestLangley , http://stackoverflow.com/a/14796445/2051938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**bevelSize : -4**

Result:

[image]

code...

[image]

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you were trying to do! That is a very clever solution.

Comment: Another way you might want to try for fun is to use THREE.LatheGeometry first, and then use Constructive Solid Geometry (CSG) to make the hole in the middle: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/

Comment: @WestLangley, To do such a thing with the CSG need to draw a second figure with which to cut it. And this is a big problem, because the dimensions must dynamically changing. And if you draw it only in "3D editor" after which. CurveSegments will not be available

Comment: @WestLangley, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801203/threecsg-bug-or-the-code-is-not-valid-three-js